# function to remove the smallest number in ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Currently trying to create a ruby function that deletes the smallest number , if that minimum number is duplicated, it should only remove the first minimum number . Here's the code that i tried

```
def RemoveSmallest(numbers)

    if numbers.count(numbers.min.uniq) > 1
      numbers.delete_at(numbers.index numbers.min.uniq)
      numbers
    else 
      numbers.delete(numbers.min)
      numbers

    end

end

puts RemoveSmallest([2,2,4,5,6])
```

this is the error

```
remove_small.rb:3:in `RemoveSmallest': undefined method `uniq' for 2:Fixnum (NoMethodError)
    from remove_small.rb:15:in `<main>'
```

im not sure why the code passes wrong when i apply `uniq` method on it

Comment: Your method should be called `remove_smallest`, not `RemoveSmallest`. Case matters a lot in Ruby, and when you use a leading uppercase letter you're creating a constant.

Comment: `numbers.delete_at(numbers.index(numbers.min))`

Comment: @meagar thanks for the feedback, quite new with ruby, reason that i use camelcase is because i read it somewhere over the web, to make the variables easier to read

Comment: @user3292755 Camel case is used for defining constants, like class and module names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`numbers.min` returns a number, not an array. You cannot invoke `uniq` on it, that's not a method on numbers.

Your code in the first branch would successfully remove only the first instance of the lowest number without `.uniq`, because `numbers.index` finds the first occurrence.

In fact, the entire if/else block is redundant. The first branch handles both types of input, so there is very little point in defining a special case for many vs one:

```
def remove_smallest(array)
  array.delete_at(array.index(array.min))
  array
end

p remove_smallest([1, 2, 3, 4])    # [2, 3, 4]
p remove_smallest([4, 3, 1, 2, 1]) # [4, 3, 2, 1]
```